# TextView on android only shows two lines worth of text in either orientation

Tags: java, android, textview

if the text is longer than the the width the textview, after the second line, it cuts it and adds "..." to the end of it. It doesnt matter the orientation, it will just display more text until the end of the second line, here is the textview XML:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/ContentViewerDescription"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="20"
                android:textColor="#999999"
                android:layout_marginTop="10px"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10px"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
and delete `android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: thank you, i didn't even think about the fact that match_parent might have something to do with it...

Comment: actually, just android:ellipsize="end"

Comment: Weird, why is ellipsize incompatible with > 2 lines?